# GUI Renderer in Android

Tags: java, android

just curious to know android Graphical components (View) have their own specific renderer  or they are using something like AWT, Swing or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have their custom renderer. Android is not using AWT or Swing. The full Android source code is available, so you can dig into it if you feel like it: https://android.googlesource.com (Information on how to download it locally is at http://source.android.com).

Basically, the entire graphics library is custom. Some concepts are similar to J2SE, but that's about it.

Comment: IMHO it's loosely based on Swing.  Some methods/classes are very similar to Swing, and some things (like the layout system) have been completely revamped.

Comment: True, the idea of layouts resembles Swing, and some layout managers are even similar (like Swing's GridLayout). You could even argue that GridBagLayout is related to RelativeLayout. But again, it's more a matter of using concepts from existing systems and making something new out of that - it'd be wrong to say that Android *uses*  Swing (not saying that anyone did).